# SQL code does not work in PHP but it does in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database that can do full queries in a table. Each user has a membership status, altough not every of these statuses are real member statuses. In this query I have to get all the users that have a real membership status. I have a filter as well, that filters the job assigmnets of the users, like "PR Manager". First, I check if there are any filters:

```
if($filter != 0)
{
    $filter = "Assignment NOT LIKE '$filter'";
}
else
{
    $filter = "1";
}
```

Next I do the search for all the real membership values:

```
$member_ids = "";
while($get = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($get["IsMember"] == 1)
    {
        $id = $get["ID"];
        if($member_ids == ""){ $member_ids = "'$id'"; } else { $member_ids .= " OR '$id'"; }
    }
}
```

From these two generated parameters then I build my SQL-query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vilma_contact WHERE Membership LIKE $member_ids AND $filter");
```

The output looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM vilma_contact WHERE Membership LIKE '3' OR '2' AND Assignment NOT LIKE '10'
```

Now for the problem. It does not run in PHP, but if I copy it to phpmyadmin it shows no errors and shows the right rows. I have never encountered something like that, I would be truly grateful is someone could help.

Comment: You should not use the old and legacy `mysql_` functions. They are marked as deprecated and might be removed anytime in the future. Rather use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: What error are you getting in PHP?

Comment: Not to mention your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: mysql_query expects resource, boolean given

Comment: i think the issue is here `Membership LIKE '3' OR '2'`

Comment: You're using `LIKE` where you should be using `=`, and besides `Membership LIKE '3' OR '2'` will do something _very_ different from what you expect.

Comment: [12.5.1. String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: For the sake of all that is lovely and pure in this world, if you're not going to PDO, at least `(int)$_GET['ID']`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM vilma_contact 
WHERE 
    Membership LIKE '3' OR '2' 
    AND Assignment NOT LIKE '10'
```

looks like bad SQL it probably should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM vilma_contact 
WHERE 
    (Membership LIKE '3' OR Membership LIKE '2') AND
    Assignment NOT LIKE '10'
```

and you probably need to be using = so further changes would be

```
SELECT * 
FROM vilma_contact 
WHERE 
    (Membership = '3' OR Membership = '2') AND
    Assignment != '10';
```

Also try adding ";" at the end

Comment: are you sure about the use of LIKE here ???? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: @Dagon just following with the original SQL, I made the suggestion to change it also

Comment: the original *wrong* sql, your answer is suppose to be the *right* sql, that's the point of answering, to correct the OP

Comment: Its not wrong sql. Syntactically it is correct. It might logically be wrong but he did not say what his intentions were.

Comment: its the wrong comparison operator to use in the is circumstance, wrong is wrong.

Comment: wrong is wrong but my answer is not. I say we duel to the death over this.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause really is in the wrong format.  Typically when using `LIKE` one would have a combinations of wildcards (`%` or `_`) in the string to actually indicate what you are matching against.  If you are trying to match those exact strings you need to use equal so maybe something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM vilma_contact
WHERE
(Membership = '3' OR Membership = '2') 
AND Assignment <> '10'
```

If you really are trying to match substrings your query might look like

```
SELECT *
FROM vilma_contact
WHERE
(Membership LIKE '%3%' OR Membership LIKE '%2%') 
AND Assignment NOT LIKE '%10%'
```

Comment: You have a typo. Assignment = '3' OR Assignment = '2' should be Membership = '3' OR Membership = '2'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the sequence of your code is correct

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vilma_contact WHERE Membership LIKE $member_ids AND $filter");`

is AFTER

`while($get = mysql_fetch_array($query))`

the error seems to indicate that there is no query before the while. So maybe you can show us the query that is being passed to the `while`?

Also as I mentioned in the comment, you need to fix the query part `Membership LIKE '3' OR '2'`